Диплинк aiogram
Всем здравствуйте! Только начал изучать aiogram и хочу переопределить deeplink, чтобы при активации бота выходил сразу справочник с командами, но что-то не так
код:
@dp.message(Command('help')) 
@dp.message(CommandStart(
    deep_link=True, magic=F.args == 'help' )) 
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(''' <u>Пожалуйста, весь список команд</u>:
1. /start - запустить бота
2. /help - справочник
3. /dice - кубик
4. /settimer - поставить таймер 
    ''')


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Ну, во-первых, скажу, что вместо """ """ пиши лучше так:
text=(
    "Текст"
    "Тоже текст, а если хочешь новую строку то в конце пиши \n"
)

А по поводу вопроса: диплинк - это вообще, грубо говоря, в основном для параметров старта бота используют, по команде /start, ты же пытаешься для команды help применить.
Просто обрабатывай команду /start, и выводи нужное сообщение при вызове:
@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        text=(
            "<u>Пожалуйста, весь список команд</u>\n"
            "1. /start - запустить бота\n"
            "2. /help - справочник\n"
            "3. /dice - кубик\n"
            "4. /settimer - поставить таймер "
        )
    )

